# Uploading large csv (5GB) to MySql Workbench

Tags: mysql, csv, import, mysql-workbench

So I have been trying to upload this csv into mysql workbench by first creating a schema then right clicking the schema and using table import wizard. This however has taken such a long time to import I have left my computer running for hours and it is still not close to being uploaded. Wondering if anyone has any tips? I tried the LOAD DATA statement but am getting a "mysql is running with a secure-file-priv option" error. Thanks!

Comment: use SHOW VARIABLES LIKE "secure_file_priv"; place your file into that directory and and LOAD DATA should now work.

5GB could take a long time, depending on the data and schema